# Is this recurrence relation equivalent to one of the definitions of the even Euler numbers.

Tags: number-theory, recurrence-relations

I've found the following recurrence relation for the even Euler numbers
$$
E_{2n}=-2^{4n}\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}\frac{2n!}{(2n-2k+1)!(2k)!}2^{-4k}E_{2k}+\frac{1}{2(2n+1)}(3^{2n+1}-1). 
$$

It looks quite similar to the definition of the Euler numbers
$$
E_{2n}=-\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}\frac{2n!}{(2n-2k)!(2k)!}E_{2k}
$$
I would like to know if these two equations are equivalent or somehow related.

Comment: This seems like a reasonable candidate for a generating-function approach; dividing the first relation by $2^{4n}(2n!)$ gives a recurrence for $2^{-4n}E_{2n}/(2n!)$ in terms of $2^{-4k}E_{2k}/(2k)!$, or in other words a recurrence relation for $f(x/4)$, where $f(x)=\sum_k \frac{x^{2k}E_{2k}}{(2k)!}$ is a sort of 'even exponential generating function' for the $E_{2k}$. Given that the second equation gives a similar recurrence relation for the EEGF $f(x)$, it should be possible to show the relation.